# .htaccess File Causing Page Not To Load Properly

Tags: html, css, server, mamp

I'm using a .htaccess file to get rid of the ".html" at the end of each URL on my website. This file works well at getting rid of the extension on all my pages except for one which displays an "Index of /" error message.

If anyone has any advice on how I'd be able to get rid of the ".html" on the URL using a MAMP server, it'd be much appreciated. Just so you know, I'm using a MAC with version 12.4 of Monterey. Is there a line of code in the .htaccess file that's interfering with the web page?

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*)\.html($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: This appears to be the same question you asked earlier with the addition of a comment that you added to the answer there. Rather than start a new question, please add an  update to the previous one by editing it and adding "Update:" followed by the information from the comment.

Comment: Also, it appears you [cross-posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) both of these questions to Stack Overflow as well. In the future, please flag the question(s) to ask a moderator to migrate them to another Stack Exchange site so that answers are not spread out among them.